# How can I keep take-away fries crispy longer?

Tags: food

It takes approximately 12 minutes to get back to my apartment from the nearest McDonalds. When I order fries and take them back home, they become soft, compared to if I consume the fries at the restaurant immediately.

The fries are packed in a paper bag with other hot food, and I do attempt to get home as soon as practical.

Is there a way to prevent the fries becoming soft during this 10~15 minutes time frame, or a way to make them crispy again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The key** is to keep the fries away from moisture.

***Factor*** - The fry must stay crisp and tasty for at least as long as it takes to eat a full serving.

Fries that comes straight out of the fryer are almost always perfectly crisp. The true test of a great fry is whether or not it remains crisp and edible a few minutes later after it's been sitting on your plate.

Use of dehydrators or desiccant can keep the fries dry during your transit time.

***Warning:*** Many Dehydrator or desiccant should be used carefully as they are toxic in nature. I would not recommend silica or chemical based dehydrator/desiccant.

**Choice 1 -** Crackers (or pieces thereof) can serve as an alternative desiccant. (Non-toxic and easily available)

[image]

**Choice 2 -** Salt is a natural dehumidifier. (Subject to weather conditions)

According to Transportation Information Service: Salt:

At up to 74% relative humidity and 20°C, salt does not absorb any appreciable quantities of water vapor. The critical water content of sodium chloride (NaCl) is 0.5% at 74% relative humidity, which is the flow moisture point at which salt begins readily to absorb water vapor, and increases such that, at 75% relative humidity, the salt dissolves.

Along with outdoor weather,  car internal weather condition is also a factor which contributes to the moisture level.

A **desiccant** is a hygroscopic substance that induces or sustains a state of dryness (desiccation) in its vicinity; It is the opposite of a humectant. Commonly encountered pre-packaged desiccants are solids that absorb water.

Comment: I am guessing the fries are already salted enough, most places sell them this way, so are you suggesting to add more salt to them? or just have some spoon of salt inside the same packaging?

Comment: 1) Add Salt - To improve the taste as per individual's choice
2) To dehumidify, keeping salt in a separate bag with air flow.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure that if you toast them in a toaster oven, they will become crispy again. Lay them out in a single layer on the toaster oven tray, or on a sheet of aluminum foil, and toast them like you would toast bread. Just be sure not to over-toast them and turn them brown; that will change their flavor.

Bonus: When you toast them some of the oil will seep out, giving you lower-calorie fries that still taste just as good.

Comment: Just make sure you eat them all.  When toasted fries get cold, they basically turn into rocks.

Answer (score 2):

As clearly stated in [this](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/14747/tricks-to-preserve-chips-french-fries) question, my suggestion to do:

1. After your purchase, let the fries reduce its temperature under a fan or on open air.
2. Transfer the entire fries to this airtight container(like the one shown below) and make sure that the lid is tightly locked.

[image]

3. Carry them back home and when required, take them directly opening the lid.
   (The same principle is used in Pringles)

Comment: Cold fries?? :(

Answer (score 1):

Eat the fries on the way home.